# When integrating Facebook Connect, should I have separate user tables for non-Facebook users and Facebook users?

Tags: database, facebook

I'm currently integrating Facebook Connect with my application which has an existing users table. Both non-Facebook and Facebook users will have the same privileges. So I was just wondering what is the best practice to managing Facebook users? Should Facebook users have their own table or should I modify my existing users table to work with Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done is the second. Have a source enum, to figure out how to authenticate, but have only 1 user table. Imagine you add many different login mechanisms, you do not want to have a user table for each one. Also, in terms of setting up your data model it will be a mess as well.

Depending on your environment something like this may already have been built, and I recommend looking at that too.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a flag to specify that a user is legacy vs. facebook. No need to over-complicate it.